# VerifySignedByAsymKey() Does Not Return Expected Value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I'm playing around with [Asymmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173744.aspx), but I don't understand the results I'm getting when I use [VerifySignedByAsymKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187791.aspx).

Why does this:

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY myasymkey 
WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_2048 
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '123pass!'; 
GO

Select VerifySignedByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('myasymkey'), 
    'Greg', 
    EncryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('myasymkey'), 'Greg'));
GO
```

Produce `0`? I was expecting it to be `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've only encrypted the data, not signed it.

See `SignByAsymKey()`. The following example returns 1:

```
declare @clear varchar(128)
set @clear = 'Greg'
Select VerifySignedByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('myasymkey'), @clear, 
       SignByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('myasymkey'), @clear, N'123pass!'))
```

Comment: Thanks, what's the point of using `SignByAsymKey()` rather than `EncryptByAsymKey()`?

Comment: Signing produces a "signature", which is a digest (hash) of the clear text that is then encrypted with the symmetric key. The signature is a way of verifying that the original data hasn't been tampered with. For non-trivial examples, it's also much shorter than the ciphertext; 128 bytes for key length of 1024 bytes, or 256 bytes for a key length of 256 bytes.